# Filter store of grid on two differents columns

Tags: javascript, sorting, extjs

I'm trying to filter a store on two columns, one with an array, and the other with the beginning of a word (It will be an AND, not an OR).
So I know how to filter a store with an array :

```
 grid.store.load().filterBy(function(record, id){
                return Ext.Array.indexOf(filter, record.get("type")) !== -1;
            }, this);
```

I know how to filter a store with the beginning of a word :

```
 {id: 'name', property: "name", value: newValue, anyMatch: true}
```

But I don't know how to combine both.

I tried :

```
        grid.store.load().filterBy(function(record, id){
            if(Ext.Array.indexOf(filter, record.get("type")) !== -1 && record.get("name").indexOf(newValue) !== -1){
                return record;
            }

        }, this);
```

But it returns me the WHOLE word, when I only want a matching to make it works. How can I do to catch part of the word ?

Comment: To be clear, you're talking about *filtering*, not *sorting*, right?

Comment: I'm not english sorry, but the filtering for a store is a sorting? Or sorting is just used for "ASC"/"DESC"? I have "Blab", "Mond", "Poh", if I write "Bl" I want "Blab" to be returned

Comment: Yes "sorting" is about putting things in some order; it looks like you're filtering, which means to select some things and not others.

Comment: @Pointy Ok so I'm talking about filtering :)

Comment: @Pointy I edited, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering stores on multiple fields of the model can be done by creating new filters every time you filter. Filtering on parts of the words can be done by setting `anyMatch` on true or by using regex.

### Filtering on one column (one field of the model)

Here I have an example created which is filtering a column of a grid using `anyMatch`.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ts4

Part of the code of the textfield (FilterField in the example app) above a column:

```
keyup: {
    fn: function(field, event, eOpts) {
        var grid = this.up('grid'),
            /* only filter when value is empty and key is backspace or delete */
            isValidKey = ((event.keyCode === Ext.event.Event.BACKSPACE || event.keyCode === Ext.event.Event.DELETE) || !event.isSpecialKey());

        if(isValidKey === true) {
            grid.getStore().filter(new Ext.util.Filter({
                anyMatch: true,
                disableOnEmpty: true,
                property: field.up('gridcolumn').dataIndex,
                value   : field.getValue()
            }));

            grid.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        }
    },
    buffer: 250
}
```

### Filtering on all columns (all fileds of the model)

Here I have an example created which is filtering on all columns of a grid using regex.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/un7

Part of the code of the controller (MainController):

```
filterStore: function(searchValue) {
    var me = this,
        grid = me.getMainGrid(),
        store = grid.getStore(),
        regex = RegExp(searchValue, 'i');

    store.clearFilter(true);

    store.filter(new Ext.util.Filter({
        filterFn: function(record) {
            var match = false;
            Ext.Object.each(record.data, function(property, value) {
                match = match || regex.test(String(value));
            });
            return match;
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this full answer, didn't know about the filterFn :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a regex. 
If someone want to filter a grid on 2 columns with an array and a value here's how you can do it :

```
grid.store.load().filterBy(function(record, id){
                var re = new RegExp("/(^"+newValue+" )", 'i');
                if(Ext.Array.indexOf(filter, record.get("type")) !== -1 && record.get("name").match(re) !== -1){
                    debugger;
                    return record;
                }

            }, this);
```